# fetchText in casperjs not returning embed link

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

Casperjs is a great way to test certain functions on various sites.

The example site I am using is part of a tutorial.

The following site offers an embed code that I am not able to console.log with
fetchText, using casperjs. Embed code can be inserted in your personal blog to link toward specific content; In this case a music album:

https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/en-us/details/1053933969

The element to scrape is the following:

```
<a href="https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/a-head-full-of-dreams/id1053933969?mt=1&amp;app=music" target="_blank">https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/a-head-full-of-dreams/id1053933969?mt=1&amp;app=music</a>
```

Following is snapshot of the inspector
[image: snapshot 1]

Two snapshots of a larger part of the markup

[image: snapshot 2]

[image: snapshot 3]

Please see the code that I have been using below:

```
var theTextIWant=casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="695806055"]/div[4]/div[2]'));
 console.log(theTextIWant);
```

No errors are returned and the script works perfectly with other links or text on the page. For example the following:

```
var theTextIWant=casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="1053933969"]/div[4]/div[2]/a'));
 console.log(theTextIWant);
```

After going through the relevant casperjs documentation I was not able to find an
alternative to fetchText on the embed code.  Am I missing something from the
casperjs documentation that would allow me to console.log the embed code?

As usual your help is much appreciated!

Let me know if you need further info.

Comment: What does *embedded* mean? Can you [edit] your question to include the markup of the element that you want to scrape?

Comment: @ArtjomB.  Yes, I was removing the selector while you answered. I will include the element to scrape, as per your request.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Edited as per your request :)

Comment: I can't access the URL. Can you show a larger chunk of the markup? The (reduced) tree from the id 695806055 should suffice. Also, is the element inside of a frame or iframe?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I included 3 snapshots that present the markup. I don't think that  the embed code does not seem to be inside a frame or iframe. Le me know if you need further info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to retrieve the *value* of the textarea. `casper.fetchText()` only concatenates TextNodes of all descendant elements of the context element that is selected, but a `<textarea>` doesn't have child TextNodes in the same way that `<input>` doesn't have them. You have to access the `value` property of the textarea which you only get access to in the [page context](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate):

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.echo(this.evaluate(function(){
        return document.getElementById("link-code").value;
    }));
});
```

Comment: This worked 100%  Thank you Artjom! I really appreciate that you took the time to look into this problem and explained the solution so clearly :)